# How to evaluate NSPredicate for one object?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsset

Is there any way to evaluate one object by predicate?
I have set of managed objects and sometimes I need for use predicate without fetch request to coreData and filter the set by predicate, but using a predicate fires faults in set at time. In this case I should turn to fault object as soon as it is no longer necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What do you mean by "evaluate one object"? Can you give an example of what you want.

Comment: Doesn't `evaluateWithObject:` on the predicate work for you?

Comment: Oh yes! I was sure that the predicate does not do so and did not read the documentation:D

Comment: What about making something like `@[your_one_object]` and work with it as with array?